# How can I keep a row highlighted even when i select another row. C# datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to highlight a line and not remove the highlight until i click again on the row.

I tried to use the CLICK event and add SELECTED = true but each time a select another line it will remove the selected to false.

Thanks,

Comment: At least put some effort while asking a question. Show something that you have tried and what obstacle you are facing.

Comment: see [DataGridView.MultiSelect Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: it doesn't work because it will need shift.. I want to mimic like a check box style. What I am trying to do with another approach I added a column to the datagridview and using like a X when selected. But when clicking again I am not getting the X that I just saved.  dataGridViewInventario.Rows[dataGridViewInventario.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value = "X";

Comment: Allow MultiSelect (!) and set row.Selected = !row.Selected in the MouseClick event!

Comment: _it doesn't work because it will need shift_ No. MultiSelect is needed for any type of mulitple selection, with or without using shift or ctrl keys

Comment: I Allowed multiselect. but still when I select another field it will remove the highlight from the previous..            dataGridViewInventario.Rows[dataGridViewInventario.CurrentRow.Index].Selected = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that I'm not happy with this solution because there is a short blink, but at least it selects the way you want:

```
List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

void selectRows()
{
    dataGridView1.SuspendLayout();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows) 
             r.Selected = selectedRows.Contains(r);
    dataGridView1.ResumeLayout();
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow clickedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;

    if (selectedRows.Contains(clickedRow))
        selectedRows.Remove(clickedRow);
    else
        selectedRows.Add(clickedRow);

    selectRows();
}
```